# Add datetime offset to UTC timestamp

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have in my code some datetime timestamps in UTC like "2022-05-20 01:00:00+00:00" and I wish to apply to them an offset like "+10:00" (or "+1000") and get as a result "2022-05-20 11:00:00+00:00"

I don't know the name of the timezone that I want to convert to, just what's its offset compared to UTC.

Is there a more direct way than applying a timedelta to my timestamp ?

Comment: Do you want to *change the timestamp*, or apply a specific timezone to it? These are two different things.

Comment: I want to convert my timestamp to a new timezone defined by the value of the offset (like +1000).

I prefer avoid timedelta as it seems inefficient (as I would have to handle offset that contains minutes too, like in South Australia), but maybe that's the only way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `2022-05-20 01:00:00+00:00` and `2022-05-20 11:00:00+00:00` are *not* the same timestamp, they're two arbitrary times with no obvious relation. What you likely want is `2022-05-20 11:00:00+10:00`, which is the same timestamp as the first one, just in a different timezone. To get there is fairly simple:

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> ts = '2022-05-20 01:00:00+00:00'
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 1, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=10))
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000))
>>> dt_loc = dt.astimezone(tz)
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 11, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000)))
>>> print(dt_loc)
2022-05-20 11:00:00+10:00
```

If you have the offset just as a string, it's simple enough to turn it into a `timezone`:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('+10:00', '%z').tzinfo
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000))
```

Works for positive and negative offsets.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to make it work using your second way, that's exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timedelta` object to add time to an existing datetime:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pytz import UTC

original_time = datetime(2022, 5, 20, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=UTC)  # 2022-05-20 01:00:00+00:00
time_diff = timedelta(hours=10)
new_time = original_time + time_diff  # 2022-05-20 11:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this method unfortunately won't have the proper offset (it should be 2022-05-20 11:00:00+10:00).

I also prefer to avoid timedelta as I would have to parse the hours, minutes and sign of the offset, then build the timedelta from this and check if I should add or substract it to my time, I was hoping to get a more direct solution.

Comment: Sadly I don't know how to help regarding the parsing - I'm sure there's a package out there can do that for you. As for the other problem, `new_time = original_time.astimezone(timezone(time_diff))` will only change the timezone (therefore changing the time too)

Comment: Regarding the parsing of offsets - you could use `datetime.strptime(offset_string, '%z').tzinfo` to get a timezone with the correct offset.